# Install telegraf agent through Powershell Script

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("administrator", $secpasswd)
$Path = "$env:userprofile\AppData\Local"

cd "$Path\telegraf"


$installtelegraf = .\telegraf.exe --service install --config "$Path\telegraf\telegraf.conf"
$start_telegraf = telegraf.exe --service start
$net_telegraf = net start telegraf


Start-Process Powershell.exe -Credential $mycreds -ArgumentList $installtelegraf $start_telegraf $net_telegraf
```

But don't know I am getting errors. I'll use this script for automation process to install it on our clients through Group Policy.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your intent is to define the command lines to invoke later with [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) *as strings*, and for that you must use *quoting*; e.g.:

```bash
# Without enclosure in '...' you would *instantly* execute the command.
$start_telegraf = 'telegraf.exe --service start'
```

To put it all together:

```bash
$installtelegraf = "telegraf.exe --service install --config `"$Path\telegraf\telegraf.conf`""
$start_telegraf = 'telegraf.exe --service start'
$net_telegraf = 'net start telegraf'

Start-Process Powershell.exe -Credential $mycreds -ArgumentList @"
$installtelegraf
$start_telegraf
$net_telegraf
"@
```

Note:

- The `$installtelegraf = ...` assignment uses an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), so as to ensure that *expansion* (string interpolation) takes place, i.e. so that `$Path` is expanded (replaced with its value); the embedded `"` chars. must therefore be escaped as `` `" ``.
- Since the other assignments do *not* require expansion, [verbatim (single-quoted) strings (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) are used.
- Note the use of an expandable [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) in the `Start-Process` call, to make it easy to pass the three variables as separate statements; alternatively, you could have used a single-line string with `;` as the statement separator.
- Note that I've removed `.\` from the first `telegraf.exe` call, as it doesn't appear in the second.

  - Generally, note that the target user must have permission to access the caller's working directory. If not, a different one must be specified via `-WorkingDirectory`.